# find element that is not duplicated in Array List using only 1 temp variable

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a scenario where i need to find the String element in Array list that is not duplicate

```
  List<String> myList=new ArrayList<String>();
  myList.add("abcd");
  myList.add("xyz");
  myList.add("xyz");
  myList.add("pqrs");     
  myList.add("pqrs");
```

And my answer should be "abcd" . I need to find this answer without using any of the collections api , just using 1 temporary variable .
Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Have you tried anything? We don't do homework here on SO.

Comment: There exist a simple approach for the case when duplicates count is 2 or any **even** number. Your example satisfies even-count rule. Is the following case possible? "non-item","dupl","dupl","dupl". If yes O(N) approach doesn't work if yes, I will post it.

Comment: do always the same strings inside the list will be next to each other ?

Comment: Is the index variable to traverse the list also counted as variable? If so, I think it is mission impossible.

Comment: I feel the `homework` tag that existed earlier should't have been removed. That way at least OP can mention that it's homework.

Comment: @KuldeepJain It was removed [with reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123758/can-we-now-discourage-the-use-of-and-burninate-the-homework-tag). OP is free to reveal or not reveal whether it's homework with words in the question. Similarly, previously OP was free to add or not add the [tag:homework] tag (except that now there's much less "is this homework? is it? is it homework? Really?" type comments, which didn't really help anyone).

Answer (score 4):

Save the first item of the list in your temp. Iterate through all items and check if another item is equal to your temp. If there is no equal item save the next item of the list in your temp. Otherwise the temp string is your first non duplicated string!

Comment: Isn't an iterator a variable?

Comment: @Dukeling recursive maybe... ^^

Comment: How is indeed the question. I think I managed to do this in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18399445/1711796). That said, I'm not sure what was actually meant by 'only one variable' in the question, I'm just making the strictest possible assumption.

Comment: What I think is that that is a homework for java beginners and he dont know how to solve it... I programed now 2 years in java I had such examples too :) like linkedlist ^^ @Dukeling so I dont think that it is so strict

Answer (score 1):

Try this but it will work -

```
int index=0;
for (int i=0;i<myList.size();i++) {
     for (int j=0;j<myList.size();j++) {
         if(i!=j && myList.get(i).equals(myList.get(j))){
             index++;
             break;
         }
     }
     if(index==0)
          System.out.println("No Duplicate Found -> "+myList.get(index));
     index=0;
}
```

Throughput `O(n*n)` will be worst.

Comment: Complexity can be improved initializing j to i and adding a break after index++.

Comment: Aren't `i`, `j` and `index` all variables?

Comment: umm.... you could i & j replace with `for-each` loop bro... actually only one veriable is index

Comment: for-each will use an iterator, thus a variable. I'm not sure what was actually meant by 'only one variable' in the question, but, if I asked it, I'd classify those as variables.

Comment: you can dig upto machine label code... ;) but its true what does he mean by "only one variable", that is confusing.

Comment: it will not work if i change my code to this                                   List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
  myList.add("xyz");
  myList.add("xyz");
  myList.add("pqrs");
  myList.add("pqrs");
  myList.add("abcd");

Answer (score 1):

The above code is working now perfectly for me

```
package com.test.spaient.sorting;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestDuplciate {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    myList.add("abc");
    myList.add("xyz");
    myList.add("xyz");
    myList.add("pqrs");
    myList.add("pqrs");

    String index = null;
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {


        index = myList.get(i);

        for (int j = 0; j < myList.size(); j++) {
            if (i != j) {
                if (index.equals(myList.get(j))) {
                    index = null;
                    break;

                }
            }
        }
              if (index != null) {
            System.out.println("non duplicate " + index);
        }

        }

    }
   }
```

Thank you for the guidance

Answer (score 0):

First you can sort it using Collection.sort() method.
now you can compare elements linearly. it will be more efficient.
because if it does not match with next element then it must not match with any other further.

 efficiency of this algorithm will be O(nlog(n)). 
nlog(n) is for sorting & n to find duplication.

Comment: I don't think Collection.sort() is allowed in the question , mentioned very clearly  "without using any of the collections api".

And can you also please explain the logic for your linear comparison ? or can write some sample code for it.

Comment: if you sort it that means equal data must be exactly next to it. so simple it take linear time to do so. all you need to do is just sort it. thats it.
& about using collection api you are right this was my slip of eye. but even you can sort a string in O(nlog n) time.

Answer (score 0):

```
  int count=0;
    for (int i=0;i<myList.size();i++)
     { count=0;
           v=myList.get(i);
          for (int j=0; j<myList.size();j++)
        {
           if (i!=j&&v.equals(myList.get(j)))
                {
                  count++;
                  break ;
                }       
        }   
        if (count==0)
        {
            System.out.println("No duplicate"+""+v);
        }     
    }
```

Comment: `i`, `j` and `count` may all classify as variables. Though I'm not sure what was actually meant by 'only one variable' in the question, I'm just making the strictest possible assumption.

Comment: well I dont see a solution in O(n). I used a for each loop initially,that should get rid of i and j

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestDuplicate {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(0);
    private static String[] skipElements;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        list.add("Test");
        list.add("xyz");
        list.add("xyz");
        list.add("pqrs");
        list.add("pqrs");
        list.add("abcd");
        skipElements = new String[list.size()];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size() ; i++){
            if(isDuplicate(list.get(i), i)){
                skipElements[i] = list.get(i);
            }
        }
        removeAllDuplicate();
        System.out.println("Non Duplicates are-->"+ list);

    }
    private static boolean isDuplicate(String element, int index){
        for(int i = index+1; i < list.size(); i++){
            if(checkExistance(element) ){
                return Boolean.TRUE;
            }else{
                
                if(element.equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(i))){
                    return Boolean.TRUE;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    private static boolean checkExistance(String element){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < skipElements.length ; i++){
            if(element.equalsIgnoreCase(skipElements[i])){
                return Boolean.TRUE;
            }
        }
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }
    
    private static void removeAllDuplicate(){
    for(int i = 0; i < skipElements.length; i++){
        if(skipElements[i] != null){
            
            removeFromList(skipElements[i]);
        }
    }
}
private static void removeFromList(String element){
    if(list.contains(element)){
        list.remove(element);
        removeFromList(element);
    }
}

}
```

Which will give you 0 or more non duplicate from the list of strings.

Other Approach with Singel Variable:

## 2:

```
public class TestDuplicateWithOneVariable {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(0);
    private static int stop = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        list.add("xyz");
        list.add("xyz");
        list.add("xyz");
        list.add("pqrs");
        list.add("pqrs");
        list.add("abcd");
        list.add("Test");
        
        while(stop >= 0){
            
            if(list.size() > 0 && list.size() > stop){
                if(isDuplicate(list.get(stop))){
                    removeFromList(list.get(stop));
                }
            }else{
                stop = -1;
            }
            
            
        }
        System.out.println("Non Duplicate-->"+list);
    }
    
    private static void removeFromList(String element){
        if(list.contains(element)){
            stop = 0;
            list.remove(element);
            removeFromList(element);
        }
    }
    
    private static boolean isDuplicate(String element){
        list.remove(element);
        if(list.contains(element)){
            return Boolean.TRUE;
        }else{
            list.add(stop,element);
            stop++;
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I imagine all 3 your `i` variables classify as variables, and, since `main` calls `isDuplicate` calls `checkExistance`, your code uses 3 variables.

Answer (score 0):

What classifies as a variable is a bit ambiguous (I believe integers and iterators are variables, but most other answers seem to disagree), I'll assume it's whatever requires a declaration, i.e. goes beyond the scope of a single statement (integer, iterator, element, whatever) (so you are allowed to do `get(i).equals(...)` without it classifying as a variable, but if you do `var = get(i); var.equals(...)`, that will be a variable).

The below assumes **the repeated elements follow on one another** and we classify duplicates as exactly 2 occurrences. 4 occurrences will classify as 2 pairs of duplicates, 6 as 3 pairs, etc.

```
static String findUnique(Iterable<String> collection)
{
   Iterator<String> iterator = collection.iterator();
   while (iterator.hasNext())
   {
      String s = iterator.next();
      if (!iterator.hasNext() || !s.equals(iterator.next()))
         return s;
   }
   return null;
}
```

Can be run using:

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("abcd", "xyz", "xyz", "pqrs", "pqrs");
System.out.println(findUnique(myList));
```

Now technically `s` is another variable, but it's local to the iteration, so it may be okay. Otherwise, modifying `Iterator` and adding a `getNextWithoutIncrement()` function will allow you to remove `s` and change the if-statement to:

```
if (!iterator.getNextWithoutIncrement().hasNext() ||
    iterator.next().equals(iterator.next()))
```

**If the repeated elements don't follow on one another**, this is a bit of a problem. Every sorting algorithm I know of uses more than a single variable (even Bubble-sort, coming in at 2 variables). However, if you're allowed to modify the list, you can use a modified Bubble-sort-like process as follows:

```
static String findUnique(List<String> collection)
{
   while (collection.size() > 0)
   {
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < collection.size()-1; i++)
         if (collection.get(i).equals(collection.get(i+1)))
            break;
         else
         {
            String s = collection.get(i);
            collection.set(i,collection.get(i+1));
            collection.set(i+1,s);
         }
      if (i == collection.size()-1)
         return collection.get(collection.size()-1);
      else
      {
         collection.remove(i);
         collection.remove(i);
      }
   }
   return null;
}
```

Call with:

```
List<String> myList= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("xyz", "abcd", "xyz", "pqrs", "pqrs"));
System.out.println(findUnique(myList));
```

Now `remove` may not be allowed, but it should be doable by changing `i` to an `Iterator` with an added `getNextWithoutIncrement` function.

And again `s` is another variable, but it's again local to the iteration, so it may be okay. Here's a bit of a hacky alternative to swap (assuming the String doesn't contain `|`):

```
collection.set(i, collection.get(i+1) + "|" + collection.get(i));
collection.set(i+1, collection.get(i).substring(collection.get(i).indexOf("|") + 1));
collection.set(i, collection.get(i).substring(0, collection.get(i).indexOf("|")));
```